# Why is my CSS Grid wrong?

Tags: html, css, grid

I am getting started with CSS Grid and I am trying to make a sign up page similar to what you have on Facebook.

it is supposed to have the first name and last name on one line, the email address on another line and a submit button on the third line. The email is supposed to span the columns.

Here is my HTML and CSS:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<title> JavaScript Form Validation. Maybe CSS Grid. </title>

<style>
    html,body{
        height : 100%;
    }
    body{
        display : flex;
        display : -webkit-flex;
        display : -moz-flex;
        justify-content : center;
        align-items : center;
    }

    form{
        display : grid;
        grid-columns : 200px 1% 200px
        grid-rows : auto 1% auto 1% auto;
        border : 1px solid black;
    }
    #fname{
        grid-column : 1;
        grid-row : 1;
    }

    #lname{
        grid-column : 3;
        grid-row : 1;
    }

    #email{
        grid-row : 2;
        grid-column-span : 3;
    }

    #submit{
        grid-row : 3;
        grid-column-span : 3;
    }

</style>
<body>
        <form>
            <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" required="true" placeholder="First Name"/>
            <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" required="true" placeholder="Last Name"/>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required="true" placeholder="Email"/>
            <button id="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
</body>
```

and the output is:

[image]

**Where have I made a mistake?** :) What needs to be changed ?

Comment: Flex has poor browser support.

Comment: @bjb568 `Grid` too ? :/

Comment: Do you have a browser that support the display grid (That's only IE10+?: See at http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/g/grid

Comment: 3 different versions, vendor prefixes, IE will support it by 2050… http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: @HerrSerker I am using the latest Chrome :)

Comment: @LittleChild There you have it. Grid is not usable. You could try this polyfill: https://github.com/codler/Grid-Layout-Polyfill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what youy are trying to achieve.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/M5KYA/18/)**

This demo uses `floats` and `box-sizing:border-box;` ([supported by IE 8 and over](http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing))

CSS :

```
html, body {
    height : 100%;
}
body {
}
form {
    border : 1px solid black;
}
input{
    box-sizing:border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    margin:0.3%;
    padding:0.3%;
    float:left;
}
#fname, #lname {
    width:49.4%;
}
#email {
    width:99.4%;
}
#submit {
    display:block;
    clear:both;
}
```